# FIle not found inside docker container

Tags: docker

please help. I missed something easy. There is my simple dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

ENV XAP_LICENSE=tryme \
XAP_NIC_ADDRESS=172.17.0.2 \
XAP_GSC_NUMBER=2

#RUN apt-get update && apt-get install
RUN addgroup --system cragroup
RUN adduser -D -g '' crauser
RUN adduser crauser cragroup

WORKDIR /home/crauser

ADD entrypoint.sh entrypoint.sh
ADD gigaspaces-xap-enterprise-12.1.1-ga-b17100 gigaspaces
RUN chmod 755 entrypoint.sh && chown crauser:cragroup entrypoint.sh
RUN chown -R crauser:cragroup /home/crauser

USER crauser

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

And there is entrypoint script:

```
#!/bin/sh

ls -la ${HOME}/gigaspaces/bin
echo Gigaspase will start ${XAP_GSC_NUMBER} containers
exec ${HOME}/gigaspaces/bin/gs-agent.sh --gsc=${XAP_GSC_NUMBER}
```

So, after build and run image I got an error

```
drwxr-xr-x    1 crauser  cragroup      4096 Jun 13  2017 .
drwxr-sr-x    1 crauser  cragroup      4096 Aug 24 05:40 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 crauser  cragroup     10458 Jun 13  2017   advanced_scripts.zip
-rwxrwxr-x    1 crauser  cragroup       744 May 27  2017 gs-agent.bat
-rwxrwxr-x    1 crauser  cragroup       576 May 27  2017 gs-agent.sh
-rwxrwxr-x    1 crauser  cragroup      1371 Mar 29  2017 gs-ui.bat
-rwxrwxr-x    1 crauser  cragroup      1312 Mar 29  2017 gs-ui.sh
-rwxrwxr-x    1 crauser  cragroup       119 Mar 29  2017 gs-webui.bat
-rwxrwxr-x    1 crauser  cragroup       122 Mar 29  2017 gs-webui.sh
-rwxrwxr-x    1 crauser  cragroup      1547 Mar 29  2017 gs.bat
-rwxrwxr-x    1 crauser  cragroup      2135 Mar 29  2017 gs.sh
-rwxrwxr-x    1 crauser  cragroup       875 Mar 29  2017 setenv-overrides.bat
-rwxrwxr-x    1 crauser  cragroup       850 Mar 29  2017 setenv-overrides.sh
-rwxrwxr-x    1 crauser  cragroup      3945 Mar 29  2017 setenv.bat
-rwxrwxr-x    1 crauser  cragroup      4017 Mar 29  2017 setenv.sh
Gigaspase will start 2 containers
./entrypoint.sh: exec: line 5: /home/crauser/gigaspaces/bin/gs-agent.sh: not found
```

As you can see, gs-agent script exists, but for some reason exec command cannot find it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you use the AUFS storage driver? I have seen strange things happen with it, especially when changing ownerships and permissions of files.

Comment: @Henry docker info shows me `Storage Driver: overlay2`

Answer (score 1):

OK, the problem was in 
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

Changing it to openjdk:8 solved problem. I do not know why.

Comment: Does the alpine base image include GNU Bash?  Does the script start with `#!/bin/bash`?